# How to run an executable file (web app) 24/7 and restart automatically when it breaks down?

Tags: server, ssh, 15.10, services, systemd

I have an executable file on a server which is a full-fledged standalone web application. When I login to a server via ssh and run the file, the website become visible in the internet. Obviously, because it's run via ssh by me, when I disconnect the website goes down.

What's the idiomatic and easy way to run that file 24/7 and preferably re-launch when it goes down?

It's Ubuntu 15 but my question is rather more broad because I want to learn how to do that on other distributives as well.

I don't want to use any third-party solutions or web services, only the standard Linux tools and applications.

Should I create a service for systemd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, creating a `systemd` service is the way to go. You will need to write a service file, which in your case doesn't need much. Here is an outline of such a file:

```
[Unit]
Description=your description here
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre= [script to run before starting the service]
ExecStart= [script to run the actual service]
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This should go in `/etc/systemd/system/yourservice.service`. Now you can start, stop, restart and find the status of your service using `systemctl` commands. Various other examples and options are to be found on the web and on this site.

This solution would be portable to all Linux systems that run `systemd`. For systems running SysV or Upstart, you will have to find a different solution.